# PHP7.0.0 is not loading on Mamp OS X

Tags: mamp

I have downloaded the PHP7.0.0 from Mamp downloads page and put it in /mamp/bin/php but It is not loading in dropdown. I know it only lists 2 PHP versions in Preferences PHP tab. All other versions lists but not PHP7.0.0

Answer (score 0):

It may just be a display issue because it's limited to two versions of PHP. In my experience there are two potential fixes:

1) you need to quit MAMP and re-open to show most recent PHP version
-or-
2) you have to hide the other versions and only leave 7.0.0 and one other version. To do this I go to MAMP/bin/php and add "_X" next to the versions of PHP that I don't want to show. For example, "php5.1.6_X". Go through all versions, so that the only ones left are php7.0.0 and any other that you would like. When done quit mamp (stop servers first if you don't have them to stop automatically) and re-open.

Comment: I have done these steps already but These are NOT working specifically with PHP7.0.0

Comment: I could not duplicate the problem (it downloaded and worked fine for me), so the only other option I can think of is to download the new version that already includes 7.0.0 on it and transfer stuff from your current install ... Here is the video I used last time: [upgrade mamp video](http://mor10.com/upgrade-mamp-3-quick-video-tutorial/). Essentially, he is saying rename current mamp, install new mamp, and transfer web and database files from old to new. If this worked let me know and I'll update my answer.